# Reduce voltage from 220V DC to 30 - 50V DC without transformer

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, transformer, dc-dc-converter

I am trying search something which I can use to convert 220V-DC to about 30-50V DC. I don't want it to be a transformer. I found some voltage regulators providing required output but not having the required input, so all useless, but there may be some available which escaped me.
You can also suggest something, which I can make at home but not too advanced for a Senior High School student. Thanks.

Edit (Thanks to @Transistor, @Asmyldof)
I am trying to make a air cleaner, so trying to power an electric motor having the given range requirement, ie, 30-50V DC.
I am converting the 220v AC mains supply to 220v DC(slightly lower) using 'bridge rectifier', which I had already made and tested.
I will also use 'filter capacitor' in the circuit (parallel) before the regulator.

Comment: "I don't want" is not a technical reason. "I only need 2 mA and a 50g transformer would be too heavy" is. So, give us the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: A buck regulator, say VIper 12, would do the job efficiently. A 180 V zener diode would be dead simple but super wasteful. What power level are we talking?

Comment: Also be aware that you seem to be designing a non-isolated power supply so that the low voltage side will be at mains potential and, for that reason, rather dangerous. What do you want to power with this circuit? Put all the information into the question and not in the comments.

Comment: And also include in that description of what it is you actually want to do and why, where does the 220VDC come from.

Comment: Be careful when dealing with mains current: by taking out the transformer you are basically eliminating a safety feature. Sounds like your physics teacher imposed this "no transformer" constraint. Can you use an optocoupler? This kind of component also provides isolation from the mains AC.

Comment: 220 VDC cannot be created without a transformer..
(or a *A LOT* of batteries)

Comment: @Edenia I couldn't understand what you are saying. Transformer is not used to create 220V DC.

Comment: @Edenia or an AC generator, a rectifier and a capacitor.

Comment: @MarcusMüller As I am trying to make air cleaner, transformer will be heavy or very heavy for my whole circuit for the device to be useful.

Comment: @winny Sorry, But I don't know the power level for the motor. You might be able to guess from these, Electric motor using electromagnetism, 30-50V. With blades for the fan of air cleaner made from CD.

Comment: @SimonB What do you mean by 'no load'?

Comment: You can't design a regulator for anything without knowing how much power it requires.

Comment: @user171450 That will produce 310V DC without the motor connected but with a capactitor on the output of the rectifier.  Once you connect a load (the motor) it will drop.  What it will drop to depends on the motor and the capacitor.

Comment: Power level is a design requirement regardless of how you go about solving it. Since you are powering it from 220 Vac mains, please don't XY problem yourself but instead get yourself a power supply suitable for the motor. There are plenty available on the market. Also, since you assumed 220 Vac would turn into 220 Vdc, I assume you have very little experience here and you are setting yourself and anyone using your contraption up for moral danger from electrocution due to missing isolation barrier. Fire comes to mind too.

Comment: @winny Yes, I am making such thing first time. Also, I am doing so much because I want to do it, not to make air cleaner, in a way, I needed something to power so I selected air cleaner, due to high pollution. It was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: Thanks all of you, I am using a buck converter buying or making(if not found).

Comment: My design is like (suggest modifications)- Mains ---------- Bridge Rectifier ----------- Filter Capacitor ----------- Buck Converter--------Motor. Is it right or I have to use switching transistor as I read somewhere.

Comment: I have to join @winny in worrying that in the situation you describe and the experience you have that you are on a very dangerous path to electrocuting yourself or someone else. Until you know what all these things mean and do, which at the moment you do not, please do not go about using mains voltages directly yourself, but ensure that you have proper and safe insulation. At the very least a full and reliable isolation transformer if you are really stubborn enough to keep with this idea. And even then 300VDC will kill you if you let it. Especially when capacitors are involved.

Comment: @Asmyldof I am reluctant to leave this. But by saying that 'I am making such thing first time', I mean that I am making 'something' with a 'lot of things' first time. I had made and worked with easier things, but connected to mains supply earlier. As you are warning,I will be special conscious. Also I will be working on it without connecting it to the electric supply, may be obvious. Connecting only after thoroughly checking the circuit. It will be out of reach of anyone after its complete, even me as I will cover the whole circuit. A LOT THANKS for Your Concern.

Comment: @DanielTork Optocoupler is used for isolation, I couldn't find anywhere that it's used to reduce voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Producing 220V unregulated DC is actually making life harder for yourself.  Buck regulators aren't normally specified to take that high an input voltage.

**If you are certain that nobody will be able to touch any live parts**, then a simple capacitive dropper circuit may work.  But it's difficult to design properly without knowing the current that will be drawn by the motor.  If it's too high, then the thing may end up more bulky than just using a transformer.

In particular, you'd need to know the starting current of the motor, which is normally a lot higher than the running current.